# Solemn, Unhurried Enigma

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, knowledge

> Scan me, seeking hidden worth.
>   Uncover prizes, gems unearth.
>   Envision! Witness! Look and find!
>   Make mazes, paths. Unmask, unwind.
>   Any means and any acts.
>   Investigate wild wacky facts.
>   Tricks make many scout in vain.
>   Calmness smooths flamed minds again.

Screwy or appropriate?

**Hint:**

> Alcohol warmth, txt injection.
>  Gumdrop govt jurisdiction.
>
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: If you take the acrostic, it almost spells "SUEMATIC", the newest technology for robotic litigators. ;P

Comment: Woooo! A Hugh Meyers riddle!

Comment: I answered it like a riddle but the tag are:  enigmatic-puzzle rhyme knowledge so the only tag I covered is rhyme :P

Comment: @YoutRied That’s cool. We all just go with whatever we see. I’ve been posting riddles for a while now and some of the old-timers have expectations I guess. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, cool:

> Every word in the puzzle, including the title, contains at least one of the two-letter state abbreviations (for example, "soleMN, uNHurRIed enigMA"). Additionally, counting the hint, all 50 of the abbreviations are present. The visual clue gives us a VW Beetle and a left arrow. Reversing (reading right-to-left) VW gives us WV, for West Virginia.

Comment: Congrats! Can you think of an appropriate synonym for “solemn, unhurried” in the title?

Comment: I'm guessing that would have to be STATELY!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Puzzling stack exchange?

Scan me, seeking hidden worth.

> Read the puzzle titles looking/seeking for good puzzles.

Uncover prizes, gems unearth.
Envision! Witness! Look and find!

> Uncover interesting puzzles, unearth cool answers, get rewarded with reputation and interesting answers, read other peoples' puzzles and ideas.

Make mazes, paths. Unmask, unwind.

> You can submit puzzles which are mazes, paths of the mind, or you can solve them by unmasking the answers and unwinding while thinking about the answer.

Any means and any acts.
Investigate wild wacky facts.

> Some puzzlers make really deep puzzles that take a lot of esoteric knowledge.

Tricks make many scout in vain.

> There are also some red herrings and tricky, non-obvious clues.

Calmness smooths flamed minds again.

> Finally you find the answer and solve the riddle burning in your mind!

Comment: Can you explain why that's the answer you picked?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you give a reason why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are typically deleted.

Comment: Added! Had to edit on a computer

Answer (score 1):

Are you the...

> Beach?

Scan me, seeking hidden worth.

> Finding a good spot to relax can be rewarding.

Uncover prizes, gems unearth.

> Beach glass and other things like shells.

Envision! Witness! Look and find!

> See previous sentence.

Make mazes, paths. Unmask, unwind.

> Unwinding is something you can do at the beach as well as making mazes in the sand.

Any means and any acts.

> People go to the beach for all sorts of reasons.

Investigate wild wacky facts.

> You can discover facts about fish or wildlife at the beach.

Tricks make many scout in vain.

> Tricks as in dumping sand down someone's back.

Calmness smooths flamed minds again.

> Going to the beach to relax.

Relation to Title:

> At the beach you are unhurried.

Comment: It's a Hugh Meyers riddle. I'm pretty sure the answer will be more self-confirming than this, probably with wordplay.